# Is there any java class to get Date from cron expression

Tags: java, date, cron, cronexpression

I need to find out the first occurrence of Date and time represented by given cron expression.
Is there any java class, utility code which can help in getting data object from given cron expression ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can check [org.quartz.CronExpression](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.com/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/1.7.3/org/quartz/CronExpression.java)
It has a method named getNextValidTimeAfter which you can use.

Answer (score 23):

You can also leverage on spring's http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html for this

```
CronSequenceGenerator generator = new CronSequenceGenerator(cronExpression);
Date nextRunDate= generator.next(new Date());
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Simple, short and docs to boot. Perfect if using Spring as there's no need to add another third-party package. Thanks.

Comment: This is for default timezone. Use this `new CronSequenceGenerator(cronExpression, your_timezone);` for specific timezone.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Spring you could use:

```
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(cron);
TriggerContext context = new TriggerContext() {

public Date lastScheduledExecutionTime() {
    return null;
}

public Date lastActualExecutionTime() {
    return null;
}

public Date lastCompletionTime() {
    return null;
}
};
return trigger.nextExecutionTime(context);
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's an alternative similar to Quartz's CronExpression but without having to add a fully fledged scheduler to your project:
[cron-utils](https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils)

You can get the date you need with the following:

```
//Get date for next execution
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
CronDefinition cronDefinition = CronDefinitionBuilder.instanceDefinitionFor(QUARTZ);
CronParser parser = new CronParser(cronDefinition);
ExecutionTime executionTime = ExecutionTime.forCron(parser.parse("* * * * * * *"));
DateTime nextExecution = executionTime.nextExecution(now));
```

According to the official description, [cron-utils](https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils) is:

> A Java library to parse, validate, migrate crons as well as get human readable descriptions for them. The project follows the Semantic Versioning Convention and uses Apache 2.0 license.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you could use either of these:

- [j-cron-expression](https://www.openhub.net/p/j-cron-expression)
- [Quartz CronTrigger class](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html)